# Binding this mousewheel event handler disables vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

My site has vertical scrolling without scrollbar and one div has horizontal scrolling without scrollbar, too.

I get the following code:

```
(function() {
  function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;

    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

    document.getElementById("premios-scroll").scrollLeft -= (delta * 40); // Multiplied by 40
    document.getElementById("premios-scroll").scrollLeft -= (delta * 40); // Multiplied by 40

    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (window.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);

    // Firefox
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
  }
  else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
  }
})();
```

It works well, but the code disables the vertical scrolling.

Here's a link of the [Website](http://sistemas.vilavelha.com.br/Newsletter/renove/html/index.html).

Comment: From what I can see `e.preventDefault()` prevents the browser from scrolling at all, and your code only seems to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

What if you only add horizontal scrolling if event mouseover target is premios-scroll?

Comment: That's an idea, but i need to show options to my boss haha